# Apache error log: setrlimit(2) error message

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache

I am using a dedicated server managed by 1and1.co.uk (Apache, Linux). My website is running fresh WordPress 3.9, PHP 5, plain CGI is enabled (no Fast CGI).

I'm trying to resolve an error in my log file which is appearing thousands of times:

> [info] [pid=7547 euid=0 egid=99] suexec.cpp(317): setrlimit(2): 2 set to  4294967295/4294967295 (soft/hard) bytes

At the exact same time as the above error appears, the following two warnings appear every time:

> Cannot get media type from 'x-mapp-cgi'
>
> Cannot get media type from'x-mapp-php4'

What does this error mean and what could be causing it?

Comment: This is not an error message just info...

Comment: @MarcellFülöp so is the server trying to do something and failing to do it?

Comment: This message is not about anything failing. It's just informational to and says that Apache applied some resource limits.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp also, it is filed under code 'error' in the log file so it is actually an error and not just 'info'.

Comment: As far as I can tell it happens on every page view or 'hit'